# Best practice for default page/service for web service URL in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asmx

I'm creating a webservice on a sub-domain, so my webservice URL is like "subdomain.domain.com" and all web service pages (*.asmx) exist this directory. 
But when i directly go to this website, it shows error page. cause there is no default page. Should i create any default web page or redirect it to any web service page? Is there any best practice for this, so that it would be secure and doesn't throw any error?

Thanks!

Comment: is this a wrong question to ask here? Can someone explain why did it get down vote?

Comment: It's a great question, but is too vague for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this would depend on if you want people to discover the web service or not, and this would depend on the needs of your individual webservice.

Also, if you want to redirect people who may leave off the *.asmx part of the url, then a default page would be handy. If your webservice has authentication on it, then it shouldn't matter if people see it.

Comment: Thanks Doozer. Yea, it has authentication and i don't want it to be discover by public. So i have added a default page.